# C#: Large File Compression

Tags: c#, 7zip, sharpziplib, file-comparison

we have large files with the size ranging from 800 MB to 900 MB. Currently i am using  SharpZipLib Library which takes more time to compress and has very less compression ratio.

Please Suggest me some of the libraries which will support high compression ratio and compressed file can be used to send over TCP\IP network

Thanks

Comment: If you delete the files then you can get them down to 0 bytes in size - this will transfer VERY FAST over any network. Then when you need them again, just rewrite them.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, this isn't a suggestion site. please take a tour of the help page to understand more about what you should ask and how to write a question

Comment: Have you considered that "has very less compression ratio" because you haven't explicitly set a compression level as per [the docs](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples)?

Comment: There is normally a balance between compression level and time needed... More compression = more time. Often more compression = much more time. You want more compression AND less time... You are going against the universe here.

Comment: @xanatos And I want a toilet made out of solid gold, but it's just not in the cards now, is it? (Austin Powers reference) :-)

Comment: Maybe try posting your code over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and ask nicely for efficiency recommendations.

Comment: @xanatos I am not against any universe here. My question clearly says.  SharpZipLib Library which takes more time to compress and has very less compression ratio.

Comment: "more time" and "less compression" than _what_?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd), a fast compressor from Facebook... In this comparison https://quixdb.github.io/squash-benchmark/#results it gives good results. There is even a .net wrapper [here](https://github.com/skbkontur/ZstdNet).

Comment: As much as I don't think this question should have been answered, especially with no code, I'm going to bookmark that and try it out next time I need zip capabilities :)